# create a folder in C:\program files and copy a dll file into

Tags: powershell

I want to create a directory in C:\program files and copy a dll file into

I can create with following PS the directory

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "C:\Program Files\admintool\zep"

my dll file is called `zep.dll`

How can I copy that zep.dll into `C:\Program Files\admintool\zep` and register it with regsvr32.exe zep.dll

The PS should create the directory and copy my dll file and register it in one step.

Is that possible??

Regards

Comment: "The PS should create the directory and copy my dll file in one step" - why is that important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Test-Path` to determine whether the directory already exists, then use `Copy-Item` to copy the file:

```
$filePath = 'C:\path\to\zep.dll'
$directoryPath = "C:\Program Files\admintool\zep"

# test if folder already exists
if(-not(Test-Path -Path $directoryPath -PathType Container)){
    # folder doesn't already exist, let's create it!
    New-Item -Path $directoryPath -ItemType Directory
}

# now copy the file
$resultingFile = Copy-Item -Path $filePath -Destination $directoryPath -PassThru

# call regsvr32 to register the newly copied library
& regsvr32 $resultingFile.FullName
```

Comment: @PerserPolis I still don't know what you mean by "one step" or why it's important :)

Comment: I want to register the DLL file after copy the DLL file with PW

Comment: Yeah, but that's obviously two operations (1. Copy file, 2. call regsvr32), so I don't know what you mean by "one step"

Comment: Ok I understand, I cannot run copy dll file and call the register command in the same PW script?

Comment: Sure you can (see updated answer), but that's still "two steps". If you want all subsequent code to abort in case something fails, set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the top of the script

Comment: Ok I will test it with updated script and let you know. Thank you very much for help

Comment: @PerserPolis I wouldn't know, I'm not an SCCM admin :) if my post answers your question, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left

Comment: Tell me please how to run the PW script with Admin right remote on the machine

Comment: @PerserPolis Run `Invoke-Command -FilePath path\to\script.ps1 -ComputerName remoteComputerName` with an account that has admin privileges on the remote machine

Comment: Hi Mathias, Thanks again for your help. Ii means I have to run for every computer a different script with computer name. I have 100 Computers. Is there no way to run for all Computers at the same time?

Comment: Of course there is: `Invoke-Command -FilePath path\to\script.ps1 -ComputerName (Get-Content path\to\list\of\computer_names.txt)`. If my post answers your question, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left

Comment: how and where can I accept your message?